# Subtables fail to be produced

Tags: tables

I'm trying to produce three sub-tables using `subtable` from `\usepackage{subcaption}`, but I continue to get a fail message. Can anyone help? Here is my entire code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array, boldline}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}    

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Demand and Supply}
\begin{subtable}
\caption{Market A}
\begin{tabular}{ P{50mm} P{50mm} P{50mm} }
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\midrule
35 & 200 & 900 \\
30 & 400 & 750 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}
\caption{Market B}
\begin{tabular}{ P{50mm} P{50mm} P{50mm} }
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\midrule
35 & 300 & 800 \\
30 & 500 & 650 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAIK you need to provide a width, e.g. `\begin{subtable}{0.4\textwidth}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a width for the `subtable`s. However, your columns are very generous. With `tabularx` you can maximize the column widths given the constraints. (**EDIT**: removed superfluous centering, as pointed out by Mico.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array, boldline}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tabularx}   

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Demand and Supply}
\begin{subtable}{0.45\textwidth}
\caption{Market A}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\midrule
35 & 200 & 900 \\
30 & 400 & 750 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}\qquad
\begin{subtable}{0.45\textwidth}
\caption{Market B}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\midrule
35 & 300 & 800 \\
30 & 500 & 650 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a version without `\centering` (big thanks to @Mico).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array, boldline}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tabularx}   

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Demand and Supply}
\quad\begin{subtable}{0.45\textwidth}
\caption{Market A}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\midrule
35 & 200 & 900 \\
30 & 400 & 750 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.45\textwidth}
\caption{Market B}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\midrule
35 & 300 & 800 \\
30 & 500 & 650 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}\quad\mbox{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. If you replace `\qquad` with `\hfill`, you can get rid of all three `\centering` directives.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! Yes, but then the tables are pushed to the left and right edge of the page. Or did you mean something like `\hfill\begin{subtable}{0.45\textwidth}...\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}{0.45\textwidth}...\end{subtable}\hfill\mbox{}`?

Comment: I meant the former. If you feel that the subtables are placed too far apart, one can always increase their widths, say to `0.475\textwidth`, right? For sure, though, the `\centering` instructions inside the `subtable` environment may be dropped as the `tabularx` environments occupy the full widths of the minipages.

Comment: @Mico Yes, that's a good point, these `\centering`'s are superfluous. (Increasing the width of the subtables will make them wider.)

Comment: Thanks! May I ask for your help once more? I would like to do the same in `threeparttable` environment, but label numbering is all messed up. Here is the link to my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548855/labels-numbering-of-threeparttable-containing-multiple-tabularx

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `\subcaptionbox`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array, boldline}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Demand and Supply}

\subcaptionbox{Market A}{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} *{3}{wc{0.16\textwidth}} @{} }
  \toprule
  Price & Demand & Supply \\
  \midrule
  35 & 200 & 900 \\
  30 & 400 & 750 \\ 
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Market B}{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} *{3}{wc{0.16\textwidth}} @{} }
  \toprule
  Price & Demand & Supply \\
  \midrule
  35 & 300 & 800 \\
  30 & 500 & 650 \\ 
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I fixed the width and used `wc{0.16\textwidth}`: you have six columns and, setting `\tabcolsep` to zero, the width should be `0.16666\textwidth`, but I left some space between the tables.

[image]