# Labels numbering of threeparttable containing multiple tabularx

Tags: tabularx, threeparttable

My tables have subtables, for which I'm using `tabularx`. To add footnote to the subtables, I'm using `threeparttable`. But the numbering is all messed up. (Without `threeparttable`, this issue is gone.) According to my research, [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361737/correcting-labels-numbering-of-threeparttable-containing-multiple-tabularx) seems to be the closest, but wasn't helpful for me. Can anyone help please? Here is my cold:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array, boldline}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tabularx}   

\usepackage{threeparttable} 

\begin{document}

Table \ref{tab:US} is the demand and supply in the U.S. with tables \ref{tab:A-US} and \ref{tab:B-US} for market A and B in the U.S.
\begin{table}
\caption{Demand and Supply in the U.S.} \label{tab:US}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
\caption{Market A} \label{tab:A-US}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
35\tnote{a} & 230 & 940 \\
30 & 410 & 750 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}\qquad
\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
\caption{Market B} \label{tab:B-US}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
35 & 300 & 800 \\
30 & 500 & 650 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] This is a price.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}



Table \ref{tab:canada} is the demand and supply in Canada with tables \ref{tab:A-canada} and \ref{tab:B-canada} for market A and B in Canada.
\begin{table}
\caption{Demand and Supply in Canada} \label{tab:canada}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
\caption{Market AA} \label{tab:A-canada}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\midrule
35\tnote{a} & 200 & 900 \\
30 & 400 & 750 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}\qquad
\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
\caption{Market BB} \label{tab:B-canada}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\midrule
35 & 300 & 800 \\
30 & 500 & 650 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] This is a price.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're using the machinery of the `threeparttable` package appropriately.

A `threeparttable` environment can have up to three formal components: a caption, a tabular-type environment (here: a `tabularx` environment), and a `tablenotes` environment. There is no provision for `subtable` environments occurring inside `threeparttable` environments. It so happens that your code doesn't crash outright. However, as you've discovered, including `subtable` environments does have a bad side-effect: the numbering of the tables and subtables gets messed up. Another indicator of things not being entirely correct is the fact that the `tablefootnote` material isn't being placed flush with the left-hand edge of the `tabularx` environments.

Usually, `threeparttable` environments are embedded in `table` environments. However, they can just as well be embedded in `subtable` environments. That's the route pursued in subtable 1a in the following example.

If the tabular-related footnotes should be labeled exclusively and consecutively as `a`, `b`, etc., and if you don't need to apply fancy formatting to the table-based footnote material, deploying the `threeparttable` machinery inside `subtable` environments may amount to overkill. As `subtable` environments are `minipage` environments, you can make do with `\footnote` directives, as is shown in subtable 2a below. (The appearance of the minipage-specific footnote markers may be reset by changing the definition of `\thempfootnote`. E.g., `\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\alph{mpfootnote}}` tells LaTeX to use upright-alphabetic characters; the default style is italic-alphabetic. You will probably also want to run `\let\footnoterule\relax` inside the `subtable`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, boldline}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs,subcaption,threeparttable} 
\usepackage{cleveref} % optional, for '\cref' and '\Cref' commands

\begin{document}

\Cref{tab:US} is the demand and supply in the U.S., with 
\cref{tab:A-US,tab:B-US} for markets A and B in the U.S.

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Demand and Supply in the U.S.} \label{tab:US}

\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
   \begin{threeparttable}
   \caption{Market A} \label{tab:A-US}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
   \toprule
   Price & Demand & Supply \\
   \cmidrule{2-3}
   35\tnote{a} & 230 & 940 \\
   30 & 410 & 750 \\ 
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabularx}
   
   \smallskip\footnotesize
   \begin{tablenotes}
   \item[a] This is a price.
   \end{tablenotes}
   \end{threeparttable}
\end{subtable} 

\medskip
\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
   \caption{Market B} \label{tab:B-US}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
   \toprule
   Price & Demand & Supply \\
   \cmidrule{2-3}
   35 & 300 & 800 \\
   30 & 500 & 650 \\ 
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabularx}
\end{subtable} 
\end{table}



\Cref{tab:canada} is the demand and supply in Canada, with 
\cref{tab:A-canada,tab:B-canada} for markets A and B in Canada.

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Demand and Supply in Canada} \label{tab:canada}
\centering

%% Note: No 'threepartable'-type directives in the following subtable:
\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
   \let\footnoterule\relax
   \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\alph{mpfootnote}} % upright-alph characters
   \caption{Market AA} \label{tab:A-canada}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
   \toprule
   Price & Demand & Supply \\
   \midrule
   35\footnote{This is a price.} & 200 & 900 \\ % Note: \footnote, not \tnote
   30 & 400 & 750 \\ 
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}

\medskip
   \begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
   \caption{Market BB} \label{tab:B-canada}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
   \toprule
   Price & Demand & Supply \\
   \midrule
   35 & 300 & 800 \\
   30 & 500 & 650 \\ 
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Mico!

Answer (score 1):

At this point I only have a workaround, similar to what you link to. Somehow `\subtable` does not seem to see that it is in a table, and increases the counter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array, boldline}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tabularx}   

\usepackage{threeparttable} 

\begin{document}

Table \ref{tab:US} is the demand and supply in the U.S. with tables \ref{tab:A-US} and \ref{tab:B-US} for market A and B in the U.S.
\begin{table}
\caption{Demand and Supply in the U.S.} \label{tab:US}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
\caption{Market A} \label{tab:A-US}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
35\tnote{a} & 230 & 940 \\
30 & 410 & 750 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}\qquad
\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
\caption{Market B} \label{tab:B-US}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
35 & 300 & 800 \\
30 & 500 & 650 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] This is a price.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}



Table \ref{tab:canada} is the demand and supply in Canada with tables \ref{tab:A-canada} and \ref{tab:B-canada} for market A and B in Canada.
\begin{table}
\caption{Demand and Supply in Canada} \label{tab:canada}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
\caption{Market AA} \label{tab:A-canada}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\midrule
35\tnote{a} & 200 & 900 \\
30 & 400 & 750 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}\qquad
\begin{subtable}{0.8\textwidth}
\caption{Market BB} \label{tab:B-canada}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{QQQ}
\toprule
Price & Demand & Supply \\
\midrule
35 & 300 & 800 \\
30 & 500 & 650 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] This is a price.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A give-away that more than the table and subtable numbering is messed up is the fact  that the material of the `tablenotes` environments is not placed correctly, i.e., not flush with the associated `tabularx` environment. I believe that unless one is willing to rewrite major portions of the `threeparttable` code, one shouldn't place `subtable` environments inside `threeparttable` environments.

Comment: Thanks so much!